# Getting data from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I have this code here:

```
<?php 

$url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=debt%20management&window=a";
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($jsonfile);

echo $obj->response[0]->list[0]->trackback_permalink;

?>
```

*Note: I have taken my API key out of the URL.

However, it returns this:

> ***Notice:*** Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\topsyAPI\index.php on line 23
>
> ***Notice:*** Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\topsyAPI\index.php on line 23
>
> ***Notice:*** Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\topsyAPI\index.php on line 23

I tried using the **true** parameter on json_decode and it's still not working.

This is the first time i've worked with an API and JSON, so I am very much new to it.. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Please note: I have tried `echo &obj->response[0]->trackback_permalink;` and `echo $obj->response->trackback_permalink` and `echo $obj->respone->list->trackback_permalink`

Comment: can you post the output of var_dump($obj);

Comment: Output the contents of your $jsonfile. I would guess it would just be incorrect json formatting or something similar.

Comment: validate your json using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: try var_dump($obj) to see what it holds.

Comment: Here is var_dump($obj) - http://pastebin.com/g7VJuxrT

Comment: should be response, not response[0]. `response` isn't an array, its an object.

Comment: try echo $obj->response->list[0]->trackback_permalink;

Comment: Thank you Shai Mishali! Done!

Comment: And cryptic! `<?php 
 
 $url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=debt%20management&window=a&apikey=E440B4A81FA04016AF0E3CAE0016DAF6";
 $jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
 $obj = json_decode($jsonfile);

 echo $obj->response->list[0]->trackback_permalink;
 

 ?>` is my final code and it works. Im so stupid! :P

Comment: try foreach($obj->response->docs as $doc)

Comment: @Blake Is there a reason Svetlio was marked the right even though I answered earlier? :)

Comment: Nope, no reason, I couldn't mark yours as right because it was an answer, however it was you who helped me and did upvote your comment! :)

Comment: Just noticed you added it as an answer too, so marked it as right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, `response` is an object, not an array. The reference should be to

```php
$obj->response->list[0]->trackback_permalink
```

*Not*

```php
$obj->response[0]->list[0]->trackback_permalink
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj->response->list[0]->trackback_permalink;
```

I think that your response is Object not array

Comment: There are things that are too small to have a full answer for :) He was answered and his problem was resolved, there's no need to be the first to write an answer just to get some points. Thats greedy.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are small or large. 
Comment is comment and Answer is answer ..

Comment: Also there's no reason to downvote as this is a full answer, if you're not able to write it as a reply it's your own fault.

Comment: Fine, I think its rather childish - since you answered after his problem was already fixed, but whatever. cheers.

Comment: @ShaiMishali We are on StackOverflow PHP section, don't expect too much `;)`